# Watch network requests or communication for processes

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, programming, network-monitor

Some days ago I was wondering if it was possible to watch a certain process network communication, and I still haven't found that.

I found Window's built-in Resource Monitor, and it actually does something close from what I wanted.

I wanted to be able to see what a process sends through the network, EXACTLY like firefox and chrome have in the Network tab, but for processes

I really am not sure if I just didn't search enough, but I'd appreciate a lot some help.

It can be anything, like a command in prompt or terminal, a library for any language, a program, and it can be for windows or linux, though I'd prefer something for windows (any version).

Thanks for the help, and sorry if I did something wrong, i'm still not familiar with forums like this

Comment: Well, you could use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/), or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), but those will only show traffic in & out of your device. I don't know of authing that will do it at the process level, and I imagine that it is going to be double difficult to find one for both Windows and Linux

Comment: See [Sniffing TCP traffic for specific process using Wireshark](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1970) and [How can I capture network traffic of a single process?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11709/561230).